# How to read an specific node from an xml

Tags: c#, xml

I have a problem reading an XML file ( C# ), the point is that I can read all elements inside `cfdi:Comprobante`, but when I want to read for example `cfdi:emisor` I'm not able to get information, even using:

```
XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();

xml.Load(vnt.FileName);

XmlElement root = xml.DocumentElement;

//gets sub total from cfdi:Comprobante

XmlAttribute total = root.GetAttributeNode("subTotal");

// HERE IS THE BIG PROBLEM

XmlAttribute rfc = root.GetAttributeNode("cfdi:Comprobante/cfdi:Emisor/rfc");

string valor = total.InnerXml;

//string rfcE = rfc.InnerText; //HERE IS THE PROBLEM

dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[2].Value = valor;

// dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[1].Value = valor;
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<cfdi:Comprobante LugarExpedicion="ZAPOPAN, JALISCO, MEXICO" metodoDePago="01" tipoDeComprobante="ingreso" total="190.00" subTotal="163.79"  noCertificado="00001000000303469404" formaDePago="PAGO EN UNA SOLA EXHIBICION" sello="TWxkop8XLoDKqh9fZe4VMBnRaf2gwYq7oP33BqLKNbBaAvfAyfAoAJ4rlTuhK3m5k9e/jiWAjTdaJ+RO8FJ6L8d5E79gCPZI2gYcVMr/ulIrIHkfiNs37FLBm87vd/0hhbt252Qefr84ALz0bl0XtsDwh6xTmoX2rzFfowXQWIw=" fecha="2017-01-13T21:23:54" folio="4594" version="3.2" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.sat.gob.mx/cfd/3 http://www.sat.gob.mx/sitio_internet/cfd/3/cfdv32.xsd http://www.buzonfiscal.com/ns/addenda/bf/2 http://www.buzonfiscal.com/schema/xsd/Addenda_BF_v20.xsd" xmlns:bfa2="http://www.buzonfiscal.com/ns/addenda/bf/2" xmlns:cfdi="http://www.sat.gob.mx/cfd/3" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <cfdi:Emisor nombre="MARIA DEL SOCORRO HERNANDEZ SEDANO" rfc="HES12211HN3">
        <cfdi:DomicilioFiscal codigoPostal="45019" pais="MEXICO" estado="JALISCO" municipio="ZAPOPAN" colonia="SAN JUAN DE OCOTAN" noExterior="7484" calle="AV VALLARTA"/>
        <cfdi:ExpedidoEn codigoPostal="43319" pais="MEXICO" estado="JALISCO" municipio="ZAPOPAN" colonia="SAN JUAN DE OCOTAN" noExterior="7484" calle="AV VALLARTA"/>
        <cfdi:RegimenFiscal Regimen="PERSONA FISICA CON ACTIVIDAD EMPRESARIAL"/>
    </cfdi:Emisor>
    <cfdi:Receptor nombre="SERVICIOS ADMINISTRATIVOS GRACIDA SC" rfc="SAG101208EJ4">
        <cfdi:Domicilio codigoPostal="45019" pais="MEXICO" estado="JALISCO" municipio="ZAPOPAN" colonia="ZAPOPAN" noExterior="401" calle="AV PROLONGACION VALLARTA"/>
    </cfdi:Receptor>
    <cfdi:Conceptos>
        <cfdi:Concepto importe="163.79" valorUnitario="163.79" descripcion="CONSUMO" noIdentificacion="001" unidad="No Aplica" cantidad="1"/>
    </cfdi:Conceptos>
    <cfdi:Impuestos totalImpuestosTrasladados="26.21">
        <cfdi:Traslados>
            <cfdi:Traslado importe="26.21" tasa="16.00" impuesto="IVA"/>
        </cfdi:Traslados>
    </cfdi:Impuestos>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a namespace table to your document:

```
XmlNamespaceManager nsmgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(xml.NameTable);
nsmgr.AddNamespace("cfdi", "http://www.sat.gob.mx/cfd/3");
```

Also, your XPath query looks a little suspect to me.  I would try this:

```
XmlElement emisor = (XmlElement)root.SelectSingleNode("cfdi:Emisor", nsmgr);
XmlAttribute rfc = emisor.GetAttributeNode("rfc");
```

Modified code sample:

```
XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();

xml.Load(vnt.FileName);

// namespace manager added here
XmlNamespaceManager nsmgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(xml.NameTable);
nsmgr.AddNamespace("cfdi", "http://www.sat.gob.mx/cfd/3");

XmlElement root = xml.DocumentElement;

//gets sub total from cfdi:Comprobante

XmlAttribute total = root.GetAttributeNode("subTotal");

// HERE IS THE BIG PROBLEM

// modified XPath query
XmlElement emisor = (XmlElement)root.SelectSingleNode("cfdi:Emisor", nsmgr);
XmlAttribute rfc = emisor.GetAttributeNode("rfc");

string valor = total.InnerXml;

//string rfcE = rfc.InnerText; //HERE IS THE PROBLEM

dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[2].Value = valor;

// dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[1].Value = valor;
```

Comment: With this code i got an error "xmlNode has not definition for GetAttributeNode"

Comment: Good catch... You have to cast to `XmlElement` first.  I've modified my code to reflect this.

Comment: still unable as im debugging the code the error is here " XmlElement emisor = (XmlElement)root.SelectSingleNode("/cfdi:Comprobante/cfdi:Emisor"); " im trying different path modes , but nothing yet :C

Comment: One more fix... sorry :( I am going to test this out in LINQPad, but for now know that the `SelectSingleNode` method requires the caller to provide the name table.  I have updated my code and will test.

Comment: That seems to work for me.  Notice how the XPath query is simply `fdi:Emisor`.  This is because the root node is `cfdi:Comprobante` so you only have to query relative to that.

Comment: WOW MEN , you helped me a lot , thak u :D

Comment: JUST ANOTHER QUESTION , in the case of <cfdi:Traslados> wich have inside <cfdi:Traslado> , how can i get the info ? , thank u

Comment: This should work: `XmlElement traslado = (XmlElement)root.SelectSingleNode("cfdi:Impuestos/cfdi:Traslados/cfdi:Traslado", nsmgr);`